# Read a string from file and convert into array Julia

Tags: arrays, file, type-conversion, julia

I have a text file like this:

```
  5
  10
  5 3 2 7 4
  2 8 4 2 5
```

I need to put the first two numbers in to different varibles as integers, I SUCCESSFULLY did that with:

```
arq = open("C:\\Users\\Breno Maia\\Desktop\\test.txt", "r")
n = readline(arq)
c = readline(arq)
n=parse(Int64, n)
c=parse(Int64, c)
```

Now, I need to put the third and forth lines in two different arrays of integers. My solution that DOESN'T work is:

```
line3=readline(arq)
line4 = readline(arq)

p= split(line3, "") //convert string into array
deleteat!(p, findall(x->x==" ", p)) //remove spaces

for i in p
   i=parse(Int64, i)
end
```

When I print line3, it shows: "SubString{String}["5", "3", "2", "7", "4"]" 
plz help. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rebinding `i` to the correct value but you are not actually updating any references within `p`.

You can do something like this: `p = map(i -> parse(Int, i), p)`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `readdlm` to simplify tasks such as this.
The first two values can be get in one line, e.g.:

```
v1,v2=filter(x->typeof(x)<:Int, permutedims(readdlm("test.txt"))[:])
```

Here is the full code that gets first value, second value, third and fourth line:

```
shell> more test.txt
5
10
5 3 2 7 4
2 8 4 2 5

julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> dat = readdlm("file.txt")
4×5 Array{Any,2}:
  5   ""   ""   ""   ""
 10   ""   ""   ""   ""
  5  3    2    7    4
  2  8    4    2    5

julia> dat[1,1], dat[2,1], Int.(dat[3,:]), Int.(dat[4,:])
(5, 10, [5, 3, 2, 7, 4], [2, 8, 4, 2, 5])
```